# How can I execute a script that needs sudo permission in the background?

Tags: bash, permissions, keyboard

Since my Asus VivoBook keyboard shortcut to change de keyboard lightning level is not working, I made a bash script and configured it to be activated when I press a combination of keys. This is my script:

```
level=$(cat /sys/class/leds/asus\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness)

[[ $level = 3 ]] && echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/asus\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness || echo $(($level+1)) | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/asus\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
```

The script is working when I run it on terminal, but when I press the keys, it doesn't, I think because of the sudo permission that requires a password. Is there any way I can change the script permissions so that when I run it in the background it doesn't request for the password?

Comment: Dear @EduardoTrápani, my question is about not needing to type password when running sudo in a specific script, not every time I write it on the terminal.

Comment: Does this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18833/49165) you question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be several options to do so, but I am suggesting you three options:

One way is to use `sudo -i` instead of `sudo`  The command is run with an environment similar to the one a user would receive at log in.

The other way is to use `sudo -v` instead of `sudo` which uses cached credentials.

The third option is to configure `sudo` to never ask you for a password.
The `visudo` command edits the `sudoers` file, which is used by the `sudo` command. To change what users and groups are allowed to run sudo, run visudo

```
sudo visudo
```

In the bottom of the file, add the following line:

```
<username> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Replace the  with your user name. Example, I will add the line

```
tejas ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Once this line is added, you can type sudo  in a Terminal window without being prompted for the password.

Note that this solution applies only while to using the `sudo` command in the terminal.

**To restrict the location in which the script can be excuted without password prompt, use the folllowing command:**

```
<username> ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/bash /path/to/script/*
```

**Strict note: use this solution only for the scripts which you can trust.**

Comment: The two first options don't work. With the first one the behaviour is the save: it asks for the password as normal. Running the second I get `usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-T timeout] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-T timeout] [-u user] file ...`

Comment: Editting the _sudoers_ works, but now when I run sudo, no matter with which app, it doesn't ask me for password either. Is there any way to write on _sudoers_ that only my file _/home/goncalo/scripts/keyboardLightning_ doesn't need password to run?

Comment: No. I want to configure the script to execute every time I press a keyboard shortcut (FN+F12). It started working when I changed the _sudoers_ file. The problem is that when I use `sudo` on terminal it doesn't ask for the passwork anymore.

Comment: use this `goncalo ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/bash /home/goncalo/scripts/keyboardLightning`

Comment: When I changed `goncalo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` on _sudoers_ it stops working and when I run it on terminal it has the original behavior: asks for my password.